# Error in configuring opencv 2.4 (pre-built) for eclipse in windows 7

Tags: c++, opencv, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to configure opencv 2.4 (pre-built) for eclipse in windows 7. For this I did the followings:

1. Installed OpenCV-2.4.0.exe in D:\opencv
2. Installed Eclipse CDT
3. Added D:\opencv\build\x64\mingw\bin to the windows system variable PATH
4. Created a simple "Helo World" opencv project in eclipse.
5. Added D:\opencv\build\include\opencv and D:\opencv\build\include\opencv2 to the Include Paths (-I) in eclipse
6. Added D:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\core_c.h and D:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\core.hpp and D:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h to the Include files (-include) in eclipse
7. Added D:\opencv\build\x64\mingw\lib to the Library search path (-L) in eclipse

When I build the project eclipse reports: "fatal error: opencv2/core/types_c.h: No such file or directory" Did I forget something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i dont know about eclipse but you should add "d:\opencv\build\include\" to your include search path

Answer (score 0):

It's abit tricky for this. If you did observe, the missing file path is " **opencv2/**core/types_c.h"
Therefore, i added these two in the include path:
1.) D:\opencv\build\include\opencv
2.) D:\opencv\build\include

(2) Will resolve the path issue. However, i don't think this is the best solution. I used this workaround for eclipse and netbeans.

Here's a link for openCV 2.2. It the same project setup as 2.2

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B
Refer to this section: "Building your own projects using OpenCV 2.2 in Visual Studio"
The listed directories and libs setup should be similar for various IDEs

Hope this helps!
Cheers!